# three js curtailment of trajectory between two vecrors

Tags: math, three.js

I have two `Vector3` points **A** and **B**.

I want to get vector **C** placed 90% of trajectory path from **A** to **B**.

How can i calculate this vector?
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vectorA.lerp( vectorB, 0.9 ); // this modifies vectorA
```

or

```
vectorC.subVectors( vectorB, vectorA ).multiplyScalar( 0.9 ).add( vectorA );
```

or

```
vectorC.copy( vectorA ).lerp( vectorB, 0.9 );
```

Maybe you can discover other ways to do it. :-)

three.js r.69

Comment: vectorC.subVectors( vectorB, vectorA ).multiplyScalar( 0.9 ).add( vectorA ) is a great and clear solution! thx

Comment: Hi, is there any way to short vector by absolute value (not %), for example by 100?

Comment: Please make a new post containing a clear statement of your new question.

Comment: sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27486949/three-js-change-vector-length-by-absolute-value thank you!